# I tried every method and failed to root my Asus MeMo Pad Me172v. Anyone know some other methods?

Tags: rooting

I have already tried SuperOneClick and Bin4ry tools to root my Asus MeMo Pad Me172v having 4.1.1 stock version, but failed to successfully root my device.

When I run SuperOneClick, it successfully reaches to step # 7 but then it just keep waiting forever. Bin4ry tool showed that I have successfully rooted my device but when i reboot it, the device remains unrooted.

There's a [thread](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php%3Ft%3D2216390&sa=U&ei=5hRmUuuQNPLE2QXTtIC4Dg&ved=0CAcQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNG0rslpUacV0WkXvaLiFtWcnsI7dg) on xda-developers forum specific for my device. I tried the method mentioned there for rooting, the screen finally showed that I have rooted my device but when I rebooted my device, there is a black screen after the modified Asus logo.

Help me root my device.

Comment: As you correctly used the `rooting` tag: have you checked [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), and followed up to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575)? You'll find a lot of (generic) methods described there as well.

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I tried every method available there. I tried this [RootX](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2239958) method also which kind of bricked my device. My device is stuck after it displays the Asus logo after rebooting. I really need help. What's the most frustating part is my device isn't some cheap Chinese device, it's made by Asus, a reputed company. Isn't there any way to root my device?

Comment: As I have no Memo Pad, I have to leave it for others to answer, sorry. Thanks for clarification, though!